# Android : FirebaseAuth - Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to make a Facebook login method for my app using firebase. i set up my Facebook app and sdk.
Logging in into Facebook works fine.. the problem is when Firebase try to `signInWithCredential` the Authentication fails. i didn't find any working solutions yet. So here's my Logcat :

```
signInWithCredential:failure
                                                           com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook:{&quot;error&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;OAuthException&quot;,&quot;code&quot;:100,&quot;fbtrace_id&quot;:&quot;CnaYlxG66lv&quot;}} ]
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxm.zzao(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwn.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxx.zzap(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdya.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxo.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Here's my Code :

- **Facebook Button and CallbackManager** :

  ```
  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
  mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
  mFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          mFacebook.setEnabled(false);
          LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SignUp.this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
          LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                  handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancel() {
                  Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                  Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Facebook Login is Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  // ...
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                  Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Facebook Login    Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  // ...
              }
          });
      }
  });
  ```
- **OnActivityResult** :

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
  ```
- **Firebase handleFacebookAccessToken** :

  ```
  private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
  Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

  AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
  mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
          .addOnCompleteListener(SignUp.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                      Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                      Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  } else {
                                                  Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                      Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Authentication failed.",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }

                  // ...
              }
          });
  }
  ```
- **Strings.xml** : everything is a copy past from the Facebook Login QuickStart
- **AndroidManifest** : everything is a copy past from the Facebook Login QuickStart aswell.
- **Project Build.gradle** :

  ```
  buildscript {

  repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
  }
  }

  allprojects {
  repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
  }
  }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
  ```
- **Firebase Console Facebook Sign-In Method** :
  [image]
- **Facebook App Basic Settings** : 
  [image]
- **Facebook App Advanced Settings** :
  [image]
- **Client OAuth Settings** :
  [image]
- **Key Hashes** : 
  [image]

I Think that's everything , if there's something else just point me and I'll update my answer , Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try and update your functions inside your onClick function. I tested the method below and it logs in. I'm having a separate issue with firebase (I believe)

```
this.fbLoginManager.registerCallback(this.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.v("Main", response.toString());
                    setProfileToView(object);
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString(GraphRequest.FIELDS_PARAM, "id, name, email, gender, birthday, picture.type(large)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }



        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: I've managed to fix my issue by chance, i disabled my old Facebook account for some reasons , but i had to create a new login app so i did that in a new Facebook acc, i got the keyhash from my app login process and i made sure everything is set up correctly so yeah , it works now. thank u

Comment: you got a +1 ;)